# DB Manager (sqlite database) Preview tab not active

Tags: qgis

I am trying to import a .shp file into DB Manager (sqlite database) and Preview tab is not active. An error also appears = VirtualElementary (QGIS 2.14.10 Essen on MACOSX)

Comment: Can you 'Save vector layers as...' as a Spatialite format?

Comment: Thanks for your input, however importing a spatialite file does not seem to work